# How find a data for the period?

Tags: sql, oracle

How find a data for the period?

- start date: `sysdate - 15 minutes`
- end date:   `sysdate`

Example:
the current date and time: `24.01.2017 12:15:00`

- start date: `24.01.2017 12:00:00`
- end date:   `24.01.2017 12:15:00`

Is there any way to do?

Comment: Why is the end date before the start date? That doesn't make any sense? Regardless, date differences are measured in terms of days. So, if you want to find out 15 minutes from a date, that's `<date> - 15/(24*60)` (because there are 24 hours in a day and 60 minutes in an hour, so there are 24*60 minutes in a day. Therefore a minute is 1/(24*60)th of a day.)

Comment: You can use intervals when computing times, such as `SELECT SYSDATE - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE FROM DUAL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  date_column BETWEEN SYSDATE - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE AND SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd do something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE DATE_FIELD BETWEEN TO_DATE('24.01.2017 12:15:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                       AND TO_DATE('24.01.2017 12:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

However, the above will return nothing because your end date is earlier than your start date. If you change your start and end dates around, however, and fix up the table and field names, you should be good.

Best of luck.